# replace version number x.x.x in a xml file while ignoring xml version='1.0'

Tags: xml, bash, shell, sed

So i am trying to script my deployment via cordova. I want to insert a version number via parameter and replace the old one.

the version number always is 3numbers divided by 2dots (like 1.2.3)

the xml file starts with  which blocks easy transformations and i am not that good with regex. My current solution is from another thread: grep version="[^0-9]*(([0-9].){0,4}[0-9][^.])" but it will result in the first line and the line i am trying to change with sed

the important lines in my xml look like this:

> "?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>  "
>
> "widget id="URL" version="1.2.3" xmlns="http://[...]">  "

my shell script wants to use sed and replace only the 1.2.3 with the new Version of the same formatting

> "sed -i.bak s/ version="expression" / version="$VERSION" /g config.xml "

Comment: If your `version` is at the start of the line, add `^` at the start.

Comment: sadly no its in another xml tag <widget id="URL" version="1.2.3" xmlns="...

Comment: Please update your question with the input XML file and your expected output

Comment: sorry. i updated the question